# Restoring a deleted branch that was previously pushed to GitHub

Tags: git, github

Given a public GitHub branch that was previously published and accessible via https://github.com/Username/repository/blob/branch-name/file.js which has since been deleted with an unknown method and is no longer accessible...

How would one restore this branch?

Comment: Was the branch deleted on GitHub or just in your local repo? Did the branch ever exist in your local repo?

Comment: We do not have any back-ups of our local repos, unfortunately. 

Searching previous commits with `git rev-list --all --pretty` shows a chunk of time missing that was previously filled by the activity from that branch.

We cannot be sure exactly how the branch was deleted.

Comment: Why don't you check to see if a colleague has the branch on their local computer? If it was not the master, it is possible someone else has it on their pc, and didn't delete it after it was deleted in the remote.

Comment: We no longer have access to the local repository, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While in git bash, on the master branch.

```
git fetch
git checkout branchname
```

If the branch is really in the repository then that will work. If not then it is gone forever. You might be able to recreate it if it was merged with your master branch, but that is a different question.

After the `git fetch` step, you may run `git branch -r` to view the remote branches. One of them should look like `origin/branchname`. Pick the `branchname` part and strip the `origin/` part.

Comment: Using the last known branch name, I get this error `error: pathspec 'lastKnownBranchname' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: `lastKnownBranchname` was supposed to be changed by you to be last known name of the branch.

Comment: It was changed to the last known name of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that deleted branches will have their detached commits pruned during the pull/fetch process, or after 90 days.

If your repo is on GitHub and you have the commit hash of the branch tip, you can retrieve the  deleted branch by using this URL format to access the tip of the branch.

`https://github.com/Username/repository/tree/725b4dcc2778e8721af761e9ae8a0983c21f1254`

You can then create a new branch within the Tree window. This will reconstruct the branch faithfully.

Often times GitHub support can give you the commit hash of the tip of the deleted branch if you don't have access to it.